Google Sheets, Automatically tovk checkbox when another cell has the word yes
I am  trying to make a Checkbox in cell F10 automatically tick when Cell F11 has the word 'Yes'
I have tried many solutions found online including the two below  and some more complicated ones and It will not work. The cell will change colour but cannot get the box to tick.
Cell F11 dose had a formula already in it to take a value from another cell in a different sheet.
=IF(F11="Yes", TRUE, FALSE)
=F11="Yes",TRUE, FALSE
I have spent a few hours searching on google and evey formula/solution I have came across hasn't worked,most of the forumlas, half work by chaging the backgorund colour that is select in the conditional formatting tool.

You need AppScript coding.

Two answers have been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.

Assuming that F10 is already a check box, you can enter the following formula in F10:
=F11="Yes"

Checkbox value set to “True” if reference contains “Yes”
Referencing @harun24hr statement, you do need Apps Script for this.
Problem Statement: You want a checkbox in cell F10 to automatically be checked when cell F11 contains the word "Yes"
Solution: Using Google Apps Script
function onEdit(e) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //Replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name

 var editedCell = e.range; // Check if the edited cell is F11 in the specified sheet

 if (sheet.getName() === 'Sheet1' && editedCell.getA1Notation() === 'F11') { // Replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name


   var cellF11 = sheet.getRange('F11').getValue(); // Get the value of cell F11

   var checkboxCell = sheet.getRange('F10'); // Get the checkbox cell F10
   if (cellF11 === 'Yes') {      
     checkboxCell.setValue(true); // If F11 contains 'Yes', check the checkbox in F10

   } else {
     checkboxCell.setValue(false); // If F11 does not contain 'Yes', uncheck the checkbox in F10
   }
 }
}

I also added that when you delete the "Yes" in the F11, the checkbox will be automatically unchecked.
Reference:
Google Apps Script  : SetValue()
